# Suggestions not appearing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

When using Visual Studio I seem to get suggestions for certain classes such as `events` in this case. I am typing `myEmitter.` and expect `on` and other methods to be offered but the only items that show are variables that I have declared myself i.e. nothing for `events`

[image]

There is a video linked here if it helps : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nho4x1pp8te0fb9/vs_nodejs_suggestions.mp4?dl=0

Comment: It's called IntelliSense and some common issues are resolved by restarting your Visual Studio or there is not sufficient code documentation for it to "suggest" in that case you can get some snippets via Nuget that'll help IntelliSense suggest. 

Read more here: https://blog.submain.com/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working/

Comment: Thanks I have tried all of that already but no luck. I now have the same issue with express not showing hints for example `app.` gives no hints after the `.` someone suggested npm install @types/express is that a likely route? This is a very recent VS install, i.e. yesterday!